# Any $2$ elements of $S$ are elements of at least one of sets $A,B,C,D$

Tags: combinatorics

$S$ is the set of the first $n$ natural numbers.

$A, B, C, D$ are subsets of $S$ such that any $2$ elements of $S$ are elements of at least one of sets $A, B, C, D$.
What is the greatest value of $k$ such that at least one of
$|A|,|B|,|C|,|D|$ is greater than $k|S|$?

I don't know where to start solving

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that it is at least 1/2 and at most 2/3?

Comment: Is the value of k dependent on n? Current phrasing sounds like no, which gives me an answer of 2/3 when n=3, but that could likely be improved on.

Comment: k is not dependent on n, I tried trial and error up to n=4, I don't know how to show that it is at least 1/2 and at most 2/3

Comment: @CalvinLin I got at most 2/3 but I didn't get at least 1/2

Answer (score 2):

wait, this is incomplete.

---

We will show that $ k \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Out of $2n-1$ elements, if the 4 subsets have at most $n-1$ elements in them, then they cover at least $ 4\times {n-1 \choose 2} $ pairs. However, there are ${2n-1 \choose 2}$ pairs that need to be covered, and since

$${2n-1 \choose 2} > 4\times {n-1 \choose 2},$$
hence one of the sets must have at least $n$ elements.

---

We will show that $k \leq \frac{3}{5}$.

For $n = 5$, the sets $ A = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, B = \{ 1, 2, 4 \}, C = \{ 1, 2, 5 \}, D = \{ 3, 4, 5 \}$ satisfy the conditions. Hence $k \leq \frac{3}{5}$.

Conversely, we can create sets where $ A = \{ n | n \equiv 1, 2, 3 \pmod{5} \}$ and similar.

---

How can we tighten this further?

For a given $n$, suppose we had such sets which satisfy the conditions and minimizes $K=\max \{ |A|, |B|, |C|, |D|\}$. The previous construction shows that $K \leq \frac{3}{5} + \frac{3}{n}$.

If $A \cup B \cup C \neq S$, then for $s \in S - A - B - C$, $\forall t \in S$, we must have $ \{ s, t \} \in D$, so $ D = S$, which gives $k = 1$. So, in an attempt to do better, we consider $ A \cup B \cup C = S$.

If $a=c=g = 0$, then $b+e+d \leq K, b+e+f \leq K, d+e+f \leq K, b+d+f+e = N$ so $3K \geq 2N$ or that $ K \geq \frac{2}{3}N$. Again, we can do better.

If $a = 0, $ then

If $ |C - A\cup B | = g > 0$, let $s_c \in C - A\cup B $ and $s_{ab} \in A \cup B$, then $\{ s_c, s_{ab} \} \in D$ so $(A \cup B) \Delta C \subset D$. So $|D| \geq a+c+g$.

[image]